# Snort track TLS version and checking rule with openssl s_client

Tags: ssl, openssl, snort

I'm getting into snort and to start out wanted to write a simple rule that sends a message when a client with a specific TLS version wants to connect. According to the documentation this can be done with `ssl_version`. My rule looks like this:

`alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 443 (msg:"testmessage"; ssl_version:tls1.0; sid:1000001;)`

I tested with `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect <ip>:<port>` and did not get an alert. After playing around with different TLS versions in `ssl_version` and `openssl s_client`, the results got me very confused. This is what I got:

| ssl_version | s_client version | msg y/n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tls1.0 | tls1 | n |
|  | tls1_1 | n |
|  | tls1_2 | y |
|  | tls1_3 | y |
| tls1.1 | tls1 | n |
|  | tls1_1 | n |
|  | tls1_2 | n |
|  | tls1_3 | n |
| tls1.2 | tls1 | y |
|  | tls1_1 | y |
|  | tls1_2 | y |
|  | tls1_3 | y |

I've found [this](https://github.com/nsacyber/Mitigating-Obsolete-TLS/blob/master/snort/obsolete%20client%20hello-tls1.txt) github repo with some rules to mitigate obsolete TLS version connections by the NSA, and it seems like my usage of `ssl_version` is correct.

Am I misunderstanding how to check my rule correctly, or is there an issue in my rule?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you write here, i.e. I get different results for the same rules: "tls1.0" always matches since this is used a TLS version in the record layer of the initial ClientHello. "tls1.1" matches for TLS 1.1 since this is the version used in further messages from the  client. Similar "tls1.2" matches for TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. If you want to further dig into the issue please provide the relevant packet captures which show what packets get actually transmitted.